# How to disable hotspot auth page in gnome?

Tags: gnome, manjaro

Whenever I boot computer, a hotspot auth webpage pops up.

How to disable it? I can't find configure in networkmanager.

The environment is manjaro+gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

> [connectivity]
>
> uri=
>
> interval=0